# How can I write the results of a recursive function into a file using C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I have managed to write down codes for a recursive function that return all the sequences of a combination without and with repetition. However, I'd like to know if someone can help me to write those results into a file(.txt, .doc, .csv, .xls, etc...) in C# using console app or windows form app.
Here are below my codes:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Combinations
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Combinations Program");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            Console.Write("Start= ");
            int start = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("End= ");
            int end = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Places= ");
            int places = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[places];

            Console.WriteLine("Combinations without repetition");
            CalcCombinationsWithoutRep(start, end, 0, arr);
 
        }

        static void CalcCombinationsWithoutRep(int start, int end, int index, int[] arr)
        {
            if (index == arr.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", arr));
                return;
                //string.Join("-", arr);
            }
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                arr[index] = i;
                //Combinations without repetition
                CalcCombinationsWithoutRep(i + 1, end, index + 1, arr);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't have a result. It has no return value and operates solely via side effects. Not that this would make any of what you want impossible, but "writing the result" doesn't really apply if there is no result.

Comment: this line of my code Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", arr)); allows me to display the result

Comment: if you run the entire code you will see the result that I'm talking about. You will get different sequences of your combination

Comment: Polygnome you are free to suggest me any solutions that will resolve my current worry.

Comment: You can always direct the output of your program via the command line. Enter the following on a command line: combinations.exe > c:\temp\output.txt

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with temporary file location

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Combinations Program");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            Console.Write("Start= ");
            int start = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("End= ");
            int end = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Places= ");
            int places = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[places];

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\result.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Combinations without repetition");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Combinations without repetition");
                CalcCombinationsWithoutRep(start, end, 0, arr, streamWriter);
            }
 
        }

        static void CalcCombinationsWithoutRep(int start, int end, int index, int[] arr, StreamWriter streamWriter)
        {
            if (index == arr.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", arr));
                streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Join("-", arr));
                return;
                //string.Join("-", arr);
            }
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                arr[index] = i;
                //Combinations without repetition
                CalcCombinationsWithoutRep(i + 1, end, index + 1, arr, streamWriter);
            }
        }
```

Next thing which you can do it is possibility to define arguments for your command line .
Useful project for this is `commandline`
https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline